# How to work around that there's no subpackage visibility in Java

Tags: java, package, visibility

When I'm writing a new component with DDD I try to have one single *public* class in a package with all collaborators of my component *package protected*.

That usually plays out very nicely, because there's only one single entry point, that clients of my component can use. All (internal) collaborators will be hidden.

Consider an example, where a client can drive around with my purpose built Java car. I don't want the client to see all internal parts of the vehicle, so only the `Car` class is exposed as public:

```
org.automobile
|- Car           <-- only Car is public
|- Engine        <-- all collaborators have default (package-protected) visibility
\- Battery
```

Now, things usually get more complicated as the domain evolves, so I want to move classes with *their* collaborators to subpackages to keep my structure nice and clean:

```
org.automobile
|- Car
|- drive.Engine           <-- how to make this only available to Car
|- drive.Spark
|- drive.Belt
|- electric.Battery       <-- and this
\- electric.BatteryCell
```

I would now like to make `Engine` and `Battery` visible to `Car` *only*, because the client of my component should still not be able to use these classes directly.

I know that there's no "subpackage" visibility in Java, but is there any other lightweight pattern of achieving what I want, short of using Java 9 modules?

Comment: Nice question and nicely written, it comes to my mind from time to time. There are some workarounds I have tried occasionally, but given the lack of sub package visibility there are some trade offs involved. Would that be of interest for this question?

Comment: Yep, sure. Show me what you've got :D

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are 2 options. Anyone feel free to chip in as this is question is interesting.

**Use a single file for java code instead of packages**

The idea is that you can use a single java file to declare the classes and API that are available to the Car.java (Engine and Battery). Classes declaring concepts hidden from Car (Spark,  Belt, BatteryCell) should be private and static so that they do not have implicit links with the declaring class.

This approach can scale but requires more work. It is also a be helpful up to a point, it is not suitable for large code bases nor for code bases that will scale in the future to be large.

```
 org.automobile
|- Car
|- Engine.java           <-- how to make this only available to Car
|- Engine.java-Spark     <--private static class in File Engine.java
|- Engine.java-Belt      <--private static class in File Engine.java
|- Battery.java               <-- package private class
\- Battery.java - BatteryCell <--private static class in File Battery.java
```

**Combine the use of abstract and protected modifiers together with subpackages**

The idea is that you create public Abstract classes whose functionality is exposed by protected methods. For instance AbstractBattery and AbstractEngine.
Then you can create some classes that act as "proxies", you extend the abstract classes with package private implementations in the package of Car and override the methods that you want to make available. For example Engine and Battery. Car will have access to the overridden methods of the abstract classes. Another side-effect is that you cannot have final API methods in your AbstractClasses.

This approach is more suitable for large code bases and aims to hide functionality and abstractions from unintended use. However it requires some more work.
Of course it is still possible for others to extend AbstractBattery and AbstractEngine and use them.

```
org.automobile
|- Car
|- Engine      <-- extends AbstractEngine, is package private, overrides methods that Car needs to  access
|- Battery     <-- extends AbstractBattery,is package private, overrides methods that Car needs to access
|- drive.AbstractEngine <-- Public abstract class with no public methods, methods that are needed by Engine and Car are protected.
|- drive.Spark <-package private
|- drive.Belt <-package private
|- electric.AbstractBattery <--Public abstract class with no public methods, methods that are needed by Battery and Car are protected.
\- electric.BatteryCell <-package private
```

Here is an example of how this could look like:

**org.automobile.engine.AbstractEngine**

```
package org.automobile.engine;

public abstract class AbstractEngine {

    protected void startEngine(){
        System.out.println("Zoom Zooomm Zoommm");
    }
}
```

**org.automobile.Engine**

```
package org.automobile;

import org.automobile.engine.AbstractEngine;

final  class Engine extends AbstractEngine {

    @Override
    protected void startEngine(){
        super.startEngine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting second approach to use an `abstract` class to establish a contract between the packages. I would definitely name the classes differently, though. Something like `EngineClient` in the base package and just `Engine` in the subpackage. I'll investigate, how this feels.

Comment: And I agree that the first approach doesn't scale well.

Comment: I would also agree regarding the naming, in fact I use to name them *Proxy, like EngineProxy and Engine. I used the naming scheme with Abstract trying to make it easy to demonstrate. P.S. If you use it feel free to add any comment or thoughts that could help.